# How to apply click handler to multiple elements inside a template -EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to apply a click event to a `span` tag inside a `div` tag.

```
items: [

        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
         '<div class="test"> Hello world<span class="icon-gear"></span></div>'
         ),
        listeners: {
          'afterrender': function(this) {
               this.el.on('click', this.onClick, this, { delegate: '.test' });
           },
           'click': function() { this.onSpanClick() }

      }]
```

and below is the click function:

```
onClick: function (e) {
   //some stuff here
},

onSpanClick: function() {
 //some stuff here
}
```

now in the above case, when clicked on the container `class="test"`, it goes into the onClick() and works as expected. However when clicked on span element, it still goes to the `onClick()` instead of going to the  `onSpanClick()`. 
Is there a way to differentiate between clicks from different elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create delegate event on your xtype. please check the below fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mcv

```
 Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
 renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
 tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
     '<div class="test"> Hello world<span class="icon-gear"> span Text</span></div>'
 ),
 itemSelector: 'div.test',
 listeners: {
     click: {
         element: 'el',
         delegate: 'div.test,span.icon-gear',
         fn: function (eopts) {
             var getClassList = eopts.target.classList;
             console.log(getClassList);
             if (getClassList.contains('test')) {
                 alert('Clicked on Test div');
             } else if (getClassList.contains('icon-gear')) {
                 alert('Clicked on span');
             }

         }
     }
 }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks... it helps me